# C++ / boost : declaring an encapsulated shared_array

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I recently started to use smart pointers. 
If I am correct, smart pointers are declared:

```
shared_array<double> a(new double[n]);
```

But how do we do if a is encapsulated in a class ?
For the moment I am doing as follow, but that seems super ugly:

header file:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int size);
    shared_array<double> _a;
};
```

source file

```
Foo::Foo(int n){
    shared_array<double> p (new double[n]);
    _a = p;
}
```

Comment: First, step back and think about things. A shared_array makes sense primarily if it's going to have shared ownership, which a class member rarely should.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: what if the class has a get method returning this shared array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the constructor initialization list:

```
Foo::Foo(int n) : _a(new double[n]) {}
```

In case you need to set the managed array in the constructor's body, then

```
Foo::Foo()
{
  int n = someCalculation();
  _a.reset(new double[n]);
}
```

Comment: thanks ! but is there a more generic way ? here the size is nicely given as parameter of the constructor, but what if the constructor requires to do some computation to find the size ? in such case, using the initialization list does not sound like the way to go.